# dotnet 5 the local source does not exist (in macOS)

Tags: macos, .net-core, nuget, devextreme, rider

I am building a .NET Core project on windows 10 with DevExtreme. I am trying to build the project on macOS big sur with Rider. When I try build my project I get this error:

> The local source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 20.2\DevExtreme\System\DevExtreme\Bin\AspNetCore' doesn't exist.

That was a path error but idk how can I fix it. I tried install DevExtremeon NPM
and restore NuGet packages but that path threw errors.

[image: error screenshot:]

Answer (score 2):

- Open the NuGet tab in Rider
- Switch to the Sources tab
- It will show you a list of all NuGet.config files which might affect the NuGet behavior for the solution
- Look for a record with `C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 20.2\DevExtreme\System\DevExtreme\Bin\AspNetCore` value
- Remove this record directly from the corresponding NuGet.config

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem. The reference to MacOS in the question appears to be irrelevant - as described, it occurred on Windows, but I encountered it with Rider on Mac.

Comment: Where can I find the NuGet files without using Rider? Is there a documentation page that lists where the system NuGet files are located on macOS and Linux?

Comment: Hey Aaron! I would start with this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior.